# Newbie getting expected expression error when compiling c code

Tags: c, compilation, cs50

I'm taking an introductory class (CS50), and I'm having trouble compiling my code.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int height;
    do
    {
        printf("Make your own pyramid!\nDetermine its height by entering an integer from 0 to 23.");
        height = GetInt();
    }
    while (height < 0 && height > 23);

    int row;
    int column;
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        if (int row == 0)
        {
        for (int column = (height - 2); column > 0;)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        {
            printf("##");
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        //etc
```

The error that comes up is:

```
mario.c:18:13: error: expected expression
        if (int row == 0)
            ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [mario] Error 1
```

I've tried looking up what "expected expression" means, but all the definitions are beyond my understanding. How do I fix this?

Comment: `if (int row == 0)` This is not valid C.. It looks like you meant `if (row == 0)`. You should brush up on C syntax. Also your loop as it's currently written is an infinite loop, you never update `column`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem areas. Once you declare an integer, you can't redeclare it in the same function. Also, the for loop requires three parameters, not two.

```
int height=100; // change 100 to desired height higher than 2.
int row; // declared here (don't use int row again in function)
int column;
for (row = 0; row < height; row++)
{
    if (row == 0)
    {
        for (column = (height - 2); column > 0;column--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
        printf("##");
}
```